# highchart/highstock navigator doesn't work with keyboard

Tags: highcharts

I'm using hightchart navigator bar in bottom. I've included the accessibility js file to use all accessible components(keyboard navigation,screen reader). Now I'm trying to navigate to navigator bar using keyboard but it doesn't work. Are there any additional properties required?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

After digging into it deeper I realized that this feature is not implemented yet in the Highstock. Could you report this idea as a feature request on the Highcharts Github issue channel? The core developers will respond to you with the workaround if you need it.

GH: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues